# Jquery animate a three levels menu not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on a three levels menu, however, I'm having difficulties to make it work properly.

Current problem: if we mouse-enter/mouseleave quickly many times, it will break all animations and menu won't open again on mouseover.

What I want:

1 - When the user is hovering the main top menu, I would like to animate the second level and fadein all links content. When the user is leaving the header section. I would like to fadeout links content and top slide the second menu level. Note: I would also like to remove the queue effect so if the user is overing the menu when this one start to close, I would like to reopen it.

2 - When the second level is visible (links), if the user is clicking on the about/contact section I'm sliding the third menu level with the correct content. Note: the second menu level has to stay visible. If the user is clicking on the close button, I'm closing the third level

3 - At any moment, if the user is leaving the header area, first I need to fade out all text, and then, slide-top the second and third menu.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

[Here is a Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b9ENU/1/)

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var slidding_menu_speed=700;
        var fadeIn_text_speed=1000;
        var close_delay=800;
        // We display London
        // On click we hide london and show au
        jQuery("header").mouseenter(function() {
            if(jQuery("#main-header").hasClass("ok")) {
            } else {
                return false
            }
            // We slide the second menu first and fadeIn the text
            jQuery("#slidding-header-menu").finish().slideDown(slidding_menu_speed, function() {
                jQuery("ul#galleries").finish().animate({
                    opacity:1
                },fadeIn_text_speed);
                jQuery("ul#pages").finish().animate({
                    opacity:1
                },fadeIn_text_speed);
            });
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            jQuery("#main-header").removeClass("ok");
            // calls close_menus after close_delay
            setTimeout(close_menus,close_delay);
            //                  close_menus();
        });
        // open and display the about section
        // or hide, increase and display the about text
        jQuery("#about").click(function() {
            // If we click on the about section and the contact section is activated
            if(jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").hasClass("active")) {
                // we fade the contact text
                jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").finish().animate({
                    opacity:0
                },fadeIn_text_speed, function() {
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").finish().removeClass("active").css({
                        display:"none"
                    });
                    //                          jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content")
                    // reduce the height of the container
                    jQuery("#relative-container-about-contact").finish().css({
                        height:"139px"
                    }).animate({
                        height:"168px"
                    }, function() {
                        // fadein contact text
                        jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").finish().addClass("active").css({
                            opacity:0
                        }).animate({
                            opacity:1
                        },fadeIn_text_speed);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // We do nothing if the about section has been clicked
                if(jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").hasClass("active")) {
                } else {
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").finish().css({
                        display:"none"
                    });
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").finish().addClass("active");
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content").slideToggle(slidding_menu_speed, function() {
                        jQuery("#relative-container-about-contact").finish().animate({
                            opacity:1
                        },fadeIn_text_speed);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        // open and display the contact section
        // or hide, increase and display  the contact text
        jQuery("#contact").click(function() {
            // If we click on the contact section and the about section is activated
            if(jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").hasClass("active")) {
                // we fade the about text
                jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").finish().animate({
                    opacity:0
                },fadeIn_text_speed, function() {
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").removeClass("active").css({
                        display:"none"
                    });
                    //                          jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content")
                    // reduce the height of the container
                    jQuery("#relative-container-about-contact").css({
                        height:"168px"
                    }).animate({
                        height:"139px"
                    }, function() {
                        // fadein contact text
                        jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").addClass("active").css({
                            opacity:0
                        }).finish().animate({
                            opacity:1
                        },fadeIn_text_speed);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // We do nothing if the contact section has been clicked
                if(jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").hasClass("active")) {
                } else {
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").css({
                        display:"none"
                    });
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").addClass("active");
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content").slideToggle(slidding_menu_speed, function() {
                        jQuery("#relative-container-about-contact").finish().animate({
                            opacity:1
                        },fadeIn_text_speed);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        // Close about and contact section
        jQuery("ul#pages #close").click(function() {
            jQuery("#relative-container-about-contact").finish().animate({
                opacity:0
            },fadeIn_text_speed, function() {
                jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content").finish().slideUp(slidding_menu_speed);
                // Remove active class
                jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").removeClass("active").css({
                    display:"block",
                    opacity:1
                });
                jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").removeClass("active").css({
                    display:"block",
                    opacity:1
                });
            });
        });
        // close all menus and init about/contact section
        function close_menus() {
            //                  $("header").unbind( "mouseenter","mouseleave");
            // We fadeout the second level text and then slide up the second menu
            jQuery("ul#pages").finish().animate({
                opacity:0
            },fadeIn_text_speed);
            jQuery("ul#galleries").finish().animate({
                opacity:0
            },fadeIn_text_speed, function() {
                jQuery("#slidding-header-menu").finish().slideUp(slidding_menu_speed, function() {
                    //                          $("header").bind( "mouseenter","mouseleave");
                    jQuery("#main-header").addClass("ok");
                });
            });
            // At the same time we fade the contact/about text and slide top the third menu
            // And initialise the contact/about content
            jQuery("#relative-container-about-contact").finish().animate({
                opacity:0
            },fadeIn_text_speed, function() {
                jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content").finish().slideUp(slidding_menu_speed, function() {
                    // Remove active class
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #contact-content").finish().removeClass("active").css({
                        display:"block",
                        opacity:1
                    });
                    jQuery("#slidding-about-contact-content #about-content").finish().removeClass("active").css({
                        display:"block",
                        opacity:1
                    });
                });
            });
        }

    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: You should use finish() only before starting a new couple of animation. I mean only once on each event handler. But not sure it is your issue here, your code is quite unreadable

Comment: What about `if(!jQuery("#main-header").hasClass("ok")){return false;}` instead of `if(jQuery("#main-header").hasClass("ok")) {} else {return false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using HoverIntent - http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

I've edited your example to use hoverIntent - http://jsfiddle.net/ek4z3/

I basically changed your `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` events into functions `over()` and `out()` respectively. You then call these functions in hoverIntent:

```
$("header").hoverIntent({
    over: over,
    out: out
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, there is an issue when the menu is closing and we mouse hover it and out. It will break all animations, on hover the menu won't slide...

Comment: Note: I update my question description to clarify animations wanted

Comment: Then you've completly changed your question. My answer answer you original question. You're now asking SO to do the whole work for you.

Comment: I complete my description to let you understand what I tried to achieve, any help on the broken animation is only what I'm asking.